# How to fix ReferenceError: window is not defined in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm using tui-calendar for my project https://github.com/nhn/toast-ui.react-calendar and got bug "ReferenceError: window is not defined" when I try to "yarn start"

```
})(window, function(__WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_tui_code_snippet__, __WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_tui_date_picker__) {
   ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Thao\Documents\Github\App\node_modules\tui-calendar\dist\tui-calendar.js:16:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
    at eval (webpack:///external_%22tui-calendar%22?:1:18)
    at Object.tui-calendar (C:\Users\Thao\Documents\Github\App\build\server.js:21026:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Thao\Documents\Github\App\build\server.js:21:30)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

If I add Calendar component while the project is running so it's work.

`import Calendar from "@toast-ui/react-calendar";`

but it's can't start with "yarn start"

What is the root cause? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some code example or a reproducible part of your code?

Comment: I'm using it like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-knuth-de09g?file=/src/App.js but I don't know why my local project can't start while codesanbox is working

Comment: Have you tried deleting node_modules folder (rm -rf node_modules) and then reinstalling using "yarn" ?

Comment: I tried. but It's still error

Comment: Are you using some custom webpack configuration or create-react-app defaults?

Comment: I'm using custom webpack config :D with typescript

Comment: Could you perhaps share that with us?

Comment: sorry I can't. this is not my project :(

Answer (score 3):

I saw `\build\server.js` in your error log. So, the root cause is highly likely the SSR.

Your UI component is either not compatible with SSR or not correctly configured. When you run `yarn start`, there's no `window` object at server side. But as you noticed, you could still make it work by importing it in a running project, whose pages have been already rendered in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
 yarn start
```

I believe it is causing because of start script. You might be building app and then and your start script is like this:

```
"start":"node build/bundle.js" // path of bundle.
```

When you do that there is no browser environment. "bundle.js" is just a regular javascript file, and in that file `window` is used but window is defined only in browser. So you have to serve your file with a server. Easier way, for development, use `webpack-dev-server`. Here is the config that you should add to the webpack.config.js:

```
devServer: {
historyApiFallback: true,
contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "build"), // build is output folder 
overlay: true,
 },
```

this is script that you should set in package.json:

```
 "start":""webpack-dev-server --open"
```

It will automatically open the browser at port 8080. This is for development environment. In production you should set a custom server like express server.